# How to format pen drive in ubuntu via command line with sudo

Tags: 14.04, command-line

How to format  pen drive in ubuntu via command line with sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erase all data, and create a single partition that takes up all USB with an ext4 filesystem:

```
printf 'o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw\n' | sudo fdisk /dev/sdX
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX1
```

Choose X based on the output of:

```
sudo lsblk
sudo fdisk -l
```

fdisk automation explained at: https://superuser.com/questions/332252/creating-and-formating-a-partition-using-a-bash-script